# TinyMCE Code Plugin - don't want to open code view in a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I need help with [TinyMCE Text Editor](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/code/).

Is it possible to open or view the code of the editor inside the editor without opening a modal?

*Something like this:*

### [image: TinyMCE Code Plugin]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code plugin that comes with TinyMCE places the HTML code is a separate window - there in no configuration option that will allow the code to appear directly in the editor's main window.

TinyMCE has a place to make such feature requests:

https://community.tinymce.com/communityIdeasHome

...so if you post something there they may add such a feature in a future release of the editor.  When you post your idea there make sure you explain why the current code dialog is insufficient for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at how TinyMCE is implemented in WordPress. Code Is editable in a text tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar request (displaying `html` source in editor) and achieved a pretty simple and (for me) sufficient solution by modifying the initial (open source) [`code`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/code/) plugin:

```
var e = tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.PluginManager"),
    p = tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.dom.DOMUtils"),
    o = function (o) {
        var e = o.getContent({source_view: !0});
        var b = o.getBody();
        if (b.getAttribute("code") === "true") {
            b.setAttribute("code", "false");
            b.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            b.style.color = "black";
            b.style.fontFamily = "Helvetica";
            o.setContent(p.DOM.decode(e));
        } else {
            b.setAttribute("code", "true");
            b.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            b.style.color = "white";
            b.style.fontFamily = "Monaco";
            o.setContent(p.DOM.encode(e));
        }
    };
```

Instead of opening a new window, it just changes the `css` of the editor (background, color, font) and sets a data-attribute (enables toggling between the initial view and the `code` view). The `p.DOM.encode(e)` then allows to display the html tags.

I'm not very experienced in javascript, but it works good so far. Anyway, feel free to correct / improve things.